# how to get labels when using model.predict()

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In my project, I have a number of cases where I have a `Dataset` instance and I need to get predictions from some model on every item in the dataset.

The `model.predict()` API is optimized perfectly for this, as shown in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict). However, there seems to be one major catch. I also happen to need the labels to compare with the predicted values, i.e. the dataset contains `x,y` pairs, and I'd like to end up with `(y_predicted, y)` pairs after the prediction is complete. This does not seem to be possible with the `predict()` API though, and I can't think of a clean way to 'split' the dataset so that the x's are fed into the model and the y's are retained to be joined back up with the predicted y's.

EDIT: I know it's quite simple to do by iterating over the dataset manually and calling the model directly, e.g.

```
for x, y in dataset:
    y_pred = model(x)
    result.append((y, y_pred))
```

However, this seems like it will be a fair bit slower than using the inbuilt predict() as Tensorflow won't be able to multi-thread/optimize the input pipeline.

Does anyone have a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you refer `tf.data.Dataset` with `Dataset` instance, you could just loop over the dataset and collect both predictions and labels in separate lists.

Comment: @Frightera I've edited my post to be more clear about the question

Comment: What I mean is you can loop over the batches of tf.data and execute `model(features)`. Can you also add the code of what you meant by iterating over the dataset?

Comment: @Frightera yeah, edited again for clarity.

Comment: If you are using the dataset api, you need at least one for loop to get the labels.

Comment: `tf.argmax(model.predict(x_test) , axis=-1)` will form an array of integers. this can be use to match labels...

Comment: Why not just use `predict` and then `zip` the resulting outputs with the list of labels?

Comment: @xdurch0 there is no list of labels. The only way to get the labels for each example is to iterate the dataset. And because it's a tfrecords dataset with multithreading, it may not be deterministic each time you iterate it.

Comment: Yeah, I was implying that you could iterate the dataset to get that list. But if it's non-deterministic, that's an issue. My answer may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the concerns you mentioned, it may be best to overwrite `predict` to suit your needs. You don't actually need to overwrite that function though, instead only `predict_step` which is called by that function. Just use this class instead of `Model`:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def predict_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        return self(x, training=False), y
```

If your model is currently `Sequential`, inherit from that instead. Basically the only change I made from the default implementation is to add `, y` to the model call result.
Note that this also makes some assumptions, such that your dataset consists of `(input, label)` batch pairs. You may need to adapt it slightly to your needs. Here is a minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


(imgs, lbls), (te_imgs, te_lbls) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

imgs = imgs.astype(np.float32).reshape((-1, 784)) / 255.
te_imgs = te_imgs.astype(np.float32).reshape((-1, 784)) / 255.

lbls = lbls.astype(np.int32)
te_lbls = te_lbls.astype(np.int32)

tr_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imgs, lbls)).shuffle(60000).batch(128)
te_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((te_imgs, te_lbls)).batch(128)


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def predict_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        return self(x, training=False), y


inp = tf.keras.Input((784,))

logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(inp)

model = MyModel(inp, logits)


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=opt)

something = model.predict(te_data)

print(something[0].shape, something[1].shape)
```

This shows `((10000, 10), (10000,))` -- `predict` now returns a tuple of `outputs, labels` (this can be confirmed by inspecting the returned labels and comparing to the images in the test set).

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know about `predict_step()`

Comment: Yup, you can do similar things with `fit` (`train_step`) and `evaluate` (`test_step`). This allows you to write custom training logic etc. but still use the convenient one-liners.